# How the value of type "i32" is evaluated in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

As per the text from spec as below:

> Note that the value types i32 and i64 are not inherently signed or unsigned. The interpretation of these types is determined by individual operators.

Since we do not know the signedness of the passing parameter of type i32, so how does the i32.add could perform the addition operation on these two parameters? And if we export this function to JavaScript, how the result should be evaluated? for example, 0xffffffff could be evaluated into different number with different signedness (4294967295 or -1).

```
(module
  (func (export "addTwo") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
    local.get 0
    local.get 1
    i32.add))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sign does not matter for addition. If you have some bits `X`, then they can be interpreted as either a signed value `S_X` or unsigned value `U_X`. The important thing is that the difference between the two is either `0` or `2^32`, because of how two's complement works.

For example if X is all 1's, then `S_X == -1` and `U_X == 2^32 - 1`. Note the difference is `2^32`. And if X is all 0's then both values are 0, and the difference is 0.

So you can write `S_X = U_X + D_X` where `D_X` is the difference, and is either 0 or `2^32`. Signed addition of `X` to `Y` is then

`S_X + S_Y = U_X + D_X + U_Y + D_Y = U_X + U_Y`

The last step is the important one: we can just ignore the `D_*` values because they are a multiple of `2^32`, and we assume that we wrap around - that is, the bits higher than 32 are just ignored.

That's **not** true for all operations. For example division has two operations, signed and unsigned, for this reason. But addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc., do not care about the sign.

Comment: Nit: multiplication does care about signedness, actually.

Comment: How does multiplication care about signedness? (wasm doesn't have different signed/unsigned multiply, nor does LLVM, etc.; the bits don't care..?)

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right, not sure where my brain had shifted.

Comment: But as I know, there are instructions like MUL and IMUL in assembly language dedicated for unsigned value and signed value multiplication. So how should I understand that "multiplication does not care about signedness"?

Comment: An assembly language that cares about overflow may care about the sign. But ignoring overflow, which is what LLVM and wasm do, the sign does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

WebAssembly requires writing `-a + b` as `b - a`.

Using [WebAssembly Explorer](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/), this:

```cpp
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

Compiles to this:

```
(i32.add(get_local $1)(get_local $0))
```

While this (note the negative `-a`):

```cpp
int add(int a, int b) { return -a + b; }
```

Compiles to this (note `sub`tract instead of `add`):

```
(i32.sub(get_local $0)(get_local $1))
```

Comment: But I didn't find such an instruction i32.add_u in the WebAssembly specification: https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/appendix/index-instructions.html, is that a customized one?